# how to tell anchor tag to got to this action in controller in rails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am new to ruby on rails. I am having problem in routes. I have a navigation menu. I have one controller home. Inside home controller I have several actions/methods. So when user clicks home, it should take user to home page by going to home controller inside home index action. When user clicks on contact then it should take him to contact action inside home controller. same goes to other links.

What I am doing is here

```
%a{:href => 'home'} Home
%a{:href => 'home/contact'} Contact
```

So when I click on contact it gives me routing error

```
No route matches [GET] "/home/contact"
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I understand you're new to rails. It looks like you have yet to read the details of how the routing works with rails.

I'd recommend starting by familiarizing yourself with the Rails guide: [Routing from the Outside In.](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) That guide describes some simple shortcuts you can use to make setting routes up much easier.

For example, one way to accomplish what you're trying to do would be to use the following:

In your `/config/routes.rb` file, put entries like these for the links you want:

```
  root :to => "home#home"
  get "home/index", :to => "home#index", :as => 'home_index'
  get "home/about", :to => "home#about", :as => 'about'
  get "home/contact", :to => "home#contact", :as => 'contact'
```

These will create short-cuts like `root_path`,  `home_index_path`, `about_path`, `contact_path`, etc that you can use in your views.

Then in your view, you'd use:

```
 %a{:href => home_index_path } Home
 %a{:href => contact_path } Contact
```

This is just te beginning of how you can use the paths. You'll want to also learn how to use rails 'restful routing' and how to put `resources` in your routing file, but that's probably beyond what you need for right now.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a a route for this URL in config/routes.rb. Something like this should work:

```
match 'home/contact' => 'home#contact`
```

I don't recommend this approach at all though since it's not RESTful and will lead to lots of messy routes and controllers. Check out the [Rails guide on routing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) for more information on how to better design routes in Rails.

Comment: I have this in routes `match "home/contact" => "home#contact", :via => :get` but now it gives me template missing error.

Comment: You really need to study Rails more. Template missing means there is no view for contact. You better use link_to also instead of %a.

Comment: @WawaLoo is right. Rails is a huge framework and you won't benefit much by just hacking away and resolving the errors as they come up. I would start with the Rails guide, but there are lots of other great free getting started resources out there. http://railsforzombies.com/ http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book

Comment: I get @WawaLoo suggestion. He is right but for now I am need this because of a strict schedule. I already had the view but was in different folder. Now I created that but all of the images are gone. I use something like this for images `%img{:src => 'assets/logo.png'}`

Comment: You need to use image_tag. Sorry, there are so many things to learn. You don't need much time. Just read through the guides, and a few hours later, you can have a better idea. You are going to loose time trying to fix things instead of learning the principles. Good luck.